# Automatic shutter speed adjustment feedback algorithm based on images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, camera

I receive real-time images from a camera. Aperture and ISO are fixed.

I need to **automatically adjust the shutter speed** to have the optimal exposure. (Goal: make an algorithm similar to a digital camera "auto-exposure")

Here is the naive algorithm I'm using:

- we start with a shutter speed / exposure time `s` and we take a frame (which will surely be underexposed or overexposed!)
- we compute the average luminance of the current frame `L1 = np.mean(x)` if `x` is the image grayscale matrix, with values from 0 to 255
- we compute the average luminance of a **gray card** that we want to use as reference: let's say we take `L2 = np.mean(y) = 120`. Note: the exposure value `EV = log2(L1)/log2(L2)`  will tell us how much we should *increase* or *decrease* the shutter speed to achieve the same luminance than the gray card
- I update the shutter speed (with a feedback from previous frame):

  ```
  s *= (120 / L1) ** 0.5
  ```

  and so on for each new camera frame, and finally it converges to an exposure which seems ok.
- Note: the exponent "0.5" was found by trial and error, it should normally not be there (see exposure value definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_value#Formal_definition)) but without it it was erratic: too high shutter speed, too small shutter speed, too high shutter speed, too small shutter speed, too high shutter speed, too small shutter speed...

But this is not optimal. Sometimes it never converges, sometimes if half the picture is very bright, and another half is very dark, it fails, and the very bright part is overexposed.

**What are common algorithms for this task?**

I have read https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11042-019-08318-1, https://github.com/MIT-Bilab/vo-autoexpose, https://www.eecs.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/fg144/Courses/10WS/pdci/talks/camera_algorithms.pdf but more general algorithms would be interesting.

Comment: Have a look at "automatic gain control", which should cover shutter speed (or exposure time) in addition to the gain factors.

Comment: @Micka Thanks. Would you have a reference in the case of image exposure / shutter speed?

Comment: For example have a look at the references from https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/RidgeRun_Auto_exposure/Auto_white_balance_library_for_DM368_and_DM365#:~:text=Auto%20exposure%20(AE)%20algorithms%20adjust,middle%20of%20the%20possible%20range.

Comment: whatever you do, it'll be a **control loop**, i.e. all the **control theory** you can find will apply to it. the control loop may be slow to respond, have a persistent offset to the target, may oscillate, diverge, be affected by saturation effects, ... all the fun things. however, with some analysis of the imaging system, you might be able to control exposure time and gain to hit the target in a single iteration. -- I don't think there are "common" algorithms. just estimate the current picture's brightness in whatever way you like, then change parameters, "observe" a few frames, iterate.